# Efficient sum of squares decomposition

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory, sums-of-squares

[Sum of 4 squares decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259152/efficient-method-to-write-number-as-a-sum-of-four-squares) is the well-known result. I'm interested only in [negative/non-negative separation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59441/zero-knowledge-range-proofs) with focus on efficiency and large numbers. I'm looking for alternatives or extensions like sum of five or with multipliers.

Any known chance to do better than expected $\log^2(n)$ time (Paul Pollack and Enrique Treviño, ["FINDING THE FOUR SQUARES IN LAGRANGE’S THEOREM"](http://pollack.uga.edu/finding4squares.pdf)) with alternatives?

Comment: You should make your question more precise. What exactly are you looking for? An algorithm? With what properties?

Comment: Thank you @Greg Martin. At the core, any non-negative number has a 4-square decomposition, with $log^2$ algorithm to find the witness. Any alternative decomposition to serve as yes/no for "is non-negative?" known, with better than $log^2$ expected running time please?

Comment: But a $\log^2$ algorithm to solve that problem is already quite good, isn't it? -- Is there any reason to hope for something still better?

Comment: @Stefan Kohl yes, $\log^2$ is not bad, still it hits the bottom line at mobile phone battery/accumulator. As stated at 6.2.6 (ProveInequality) of IBM report 3730 (Idemix), "this step accounts for substantial fraction of the computational time of this protocol". As cited by "Ginswich", "complexity..is governed by the cost of finding these squares". I do have my reason with "private location verification" on larger scale (linkedin).

Comment: So, you have an integer, and you want to know whether it's positive or negative? Why not just look at it, and see whether it has a minus sign out front?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That four numbers are considered a witness to "is non-negative" relation, and a private input to an interactive proof system (a Schnorr-like protocol). The number itself is not available to verifier. For example http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/363

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an efficient way to do so. Proceed like that to find four numbers $a, b, c, d$, having their squares add up to a given integer:

1. Given a random number $n$, assign $a:=\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$.
2. Assign $b:=\lfloor{\sqrt{n-a^2}}\rfloor$.
3. Call the remainder $m:=n-a^2-b^2$. Check, in this order:
4. Is $m\equiv 1$ $(\mathop{mod} 4)$? If not, decrease $a$ by $1$ and go to Step 2.
5. Is $m$ prime? If not, decrease $a$ by $1$ and go to Step 2.
6. $p:=m$ is now a prime $\equiv 1$ $(\mathop{mod} 4)$.
7. Find a square root of $-1$ $(\mathop{mod} p)$. A common way to do this is to take random numbers $x$ and compute $y=x^{(p-1) \over 4}$. $y^2 \equiv -1$ $(\mathop{mod} p)$ sometimes.
8. $r:=y$ is now a square root of $-1$.
9. This allows to state $r^2 + 1^2 \equiv 0$ $(\mathop{mod} p)$.
10. Now, use the euclidean algorithm to find a factor $s$ of $r$ so that $s\approx{\sqrt{p}}$ and $r\cdot s\approx{\sqrt{p}}$ $(\mathop{mod} p)$ ([Thue's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%27s_lemma))
11. Step 10 always appears to find two numbers whose squares add up to $p$. This means we found the missing two squares.

Finding a suitable prime is not hard. It depends on the density of primes around $n^{1\over 4}$. Roots of $-1$ are readily available modulo these primes. The ("extended") euclidean algorithm isn't hard, either. I do not know why, but it always appears to find exactly the two squares that fit. They even turn up twice, once with a flipped sign.

Comment: Thank you! Let me run it and see how it go.

Comment: May I ask how it went? I'm also quite interested in finding an algorithm faster than Rabin-Shallit (I'm fine with assumptions, I'm happy if it just works very well in practice for integers in the 32 bits to 64 bits range)

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions. I'm reading you.

Answer (score 0):

Another representation was found, in five or more variables,
Theorem XII on the last page of

L. E. Dickson, Quaternary Quadratic Forms Representing all Integers
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1927-33-01/S0002-9904-1927-04312-9/S0002-9904-1927-04312-9.pdf

The major part of the question remains on faster algoritms finding such a representation. Citing Idemix specifications (RZ 3730), Rabin-Shallit algorithm "accounts for a substantial fraction of the computation time" of an interactive argument (section 6.2.6).